# If a chord progression with a minor tonic has no chords with a leading tone, does that mean it is aeolian?

Tags: chord-progressions

If we take a progression like i III VII iv, does the absence of a raised leading tone mean we arent in a minor key? Are progressions like these "modal" progressions?

Comment: In the words of Ted Greene, " _key means the center_ " https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rLPeB5GyMpI&t=685s

Comment: How certain can we be of a minor tonic if the leading tone of that minor tonic isn't anywhere in the chord progression? Note that the stereotypical *major-key* chord progression vi-IV-I-V sounds just like i-VI-III-VII in the relative minor.

Comment: Can someone explain the RN convention used by armani? E.g. in the context of conventions used here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_numeral_analysis#Diatonic_scales ? What chords are III and VII? Don't they both contain the leading tone?!

Comment: @user1079505 Their III and VII are the bIII and bVII of that Wikipedia section.

Comment: @Richard how do you know that? Is this RN convention documented somewhere?

Comment: @user1079505 I would argue that armani's use *is* the convention, and the Wikipedia article is a little out of convention. Typically, an accidental before the Roman numeral means altering the root of the chord from the key signature. In C minor, the mediant scale degree is E-flat, so that chord should be written as III, not as bIII (which would literally mean an E-doubleflat chord). This is admittedly a little pedantic, though; in context we simply know that bIII and III almost always mean the same thing.

Comment: @user1079505 In any event, III, certainly does *not* have the leading tone in minor; that would create an augmented triad, which is exceedingly rare as compared to the major triad built on scale-degree 3.

Comment: dekka, does the leading tone have to be there, doesnt the chord progression start and end on the i chord make it sound like i is the tonic even without a leading tone?

Comment: @armani Different people use the word "key" in different meanings in different situations. In the example I linked, Ted Greene used key to mean only the center. What is your usage here, what do you want to be able to _do_ by categorizing something as being in a key or not in a key? What are you trying to do? Language is a tool that's used to DO something. What are you trying to accomplish.

Comment: @Richard then what is the RN symbol for Bo chord in the key of Cm? #viio?

Answer (score 2):

I only studied some classical theory but not medieval theory. Since you care about minor mode and chord progressions, I'll talk about the classical theory.

First of all, to establish a key in classical music, one needs to have reinforcing cadences. Composers may introduce additional notes to hint the key, but until enough reinforcement shows up, a key is ambiguous. So yes, i III VI iv alone doesn't give you a minor key.

You probably shouldn't even label the chords this way in the first place because you don't know what "key" it's in. It's just for communication so people know what kind of chords you're talking about.

As for whether they should be called "modal progressions", it really depends on what context you put them in. If you see a passage like this in classical music, and it never gives you any leading tone, it's probably just an ambiguous section, or part of a larger minor section. If it's an earlier music, well, you just don't label them with Roman numerals.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Aeolian - or Dorian - or Phrygian. All of which are *minor* modes - there is nothing that's a minor tonic - minor modes due to the m3 between tonic and 3rd.

The raised leading note came about centuries ago, mainly to make the V sound more like a dominant, leading to the tonic. It's not *necessary* to include it in any minor piece, it's just that it *does* get included, for reasons above.

Aeolian, Dorian and Phrygian *may* come under the 'minor key' banner for some, and under 'minor mode' for others. But a piece which uses A B C D E F and G only are certainly in minor modes, if not, for all, minor keys, all possessing the 'flattened' (or rather),'not raised' leading note. That aspect alone is not enough to prove something is 'in minor', in fact, it isn't even a criterion!

Comment: Slightly pedantic comment: the leading tone came about *before* the concept of the triad, so it precedes the notion of "V" by quite a bit.

Comment: "Tonic" typically denotes a chord, which is typically denotes with the Roman numeral I or i, depending on whether the tonic chord is major or minor.

Comment: @phoog - to me, at least, *tonic* is the name given to the first degree of a major or minor scale - the key-note. That will inevitably lead to a chord in a key, but I'm going to disagree that it 'typically' denotes a chord (I or i) over and above a  single note. Maybe a question..?

Comment: @Tim yes, it is the name given to the first degree of the major or minor scale, just as "dominant" is originally the name given to the fifth degree.  In both cases, though, the name is also applied to the chord built on the corresponding degree, as are "mediant," "submediant," and "subdominant."  See for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Scale_degrees_with_chords.png